# nodejs pm2 server takes too much resources?

Tags: node.js, next.js, pm2, next.js13

Like when i request a website in broser tike also most full resource myserver specification is 2gb ram and dual core ubunutu bases i have hosted website using pm2 what could be the posibility is that nodejs app are not quite good

try restarting also reinstalling it

***now i upgraded to 4gb******
server during ideal state
[image]

server during lower traffic or while singe request state [image]

first is top 3 are pm2 server
these are two pm2 servers instances for load balcing which tak too ram i guess
[image]

Comment: You may have a memory leak. Node web servers typically use around 20MB to 40MB of RAM. Do you use any caching in your code?

Comment: it not like other when there smaller traffic to server not only it  takes some ram but also CPU to 100% to each core now i don't have quite optional was i upgraded my to 4 gb right now like

Answer (score 0):

Try adding --ignore-watch="node_modules"

```
pm2 start <your_app> --watch --ignore-watch="node_modules"
```

Alternatively, you can add the ignore_watch field to your PM2 configuration file

Reference: https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/1314